# Concat Observables of different types

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, reactivex

I have a network call that authenticates and receives a token and a second one that, using this token, requests data.

I want to combine those into a `Single<Data>`. In order to do so I was looking at `concat`, but this seems to only work for `Observable` of the same type. Using `zip` I could return just the response of the second `Observable`, but to my understanding it works in paralell while I need to wait for the first `Observable` and handle its response before I can start the second one.

What would be the operator I should use for this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since request token and request data are dependent steps then use flatMap:

```
Observable<String> getToken(String user, String password) {
   ...
}

Single<Data> getData(String token) {
   ...
}
```

Usage:

```
Single<Data> data = getToken(user, pass).flatMap(token -> getData(token))
```